# How to include HTML badges as labels in column chart?

Tags: javascript, charts, plotly

```js
var xValue = ['1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9','10','11','12','13'];
var yValue = [10, 6, 8,9,1,17,3,7,13,2,12,4,13];
var wicket1 = ['W','','W','W','','','','W','','','','','W'];

var trace1 = {
  x: xValue,
  y: yValue,
  type: 'bar',
  text: wicket1,
  textposition: 'outside',
};

var data1 = [trace1];

Plotly.newPlot('myDiv', data1);
```

```html
  <script src="https://cdn.plot.ly/plotly-latest.min.js"></script>
  <div id="myDiv"></div>
```

Comment: what do you mean with *badges*?

Comment: I need to replace 'W' with <span class="badge">W</span>

Comment: It depends on the specific chart library that you are using. You should probably be asking this on their Github page.

Answer (score 1):

I hope this is what you are looking for, I am not able to make it work using class, but if I add the styles inline it works great, hope that is acceptable.

Only some styles seem to work, so place the styles of "badge" as inline styles and see if your required output is produced.

```js
var xValue = ['1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9','10','11','12','13'];
var yValue = [10, 6, 8,9,1,17,3,7,13,2,12,4,13];
var wicket1 = ['W','','W','W','','','','W','','','','','W'].map(function(el) {
return '<span style="color:blue;">'+el+'</span>'
});;

var trace1 = {
  x: xValue,
  y: yValue,
  type: 'bar',
  text: wicket1,
  textposition: 'outside',
};

var data1 = [trace1];

Plotly.newPlot('myDiv', data1);
```

```html
  <script src="https://cdn.plot.ly/plotly-latest.min.js"></script>
  <div id="myDiv"></div>
```

Comment: @FaLIL Does this answer help you

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is possible, the script creates a SVG file. Inside these g-tags you can place text and images. But you need to do it in SVG. (text=`<text x="0" y="15" fill="red">Your text here</text>`)
[image]

Comment: may i get a sample code to generate a simple column chart using SVG??

Comment: You can't just make a column chart using SVG, but you can add text to them using js

Comment: cant make a column chart using SVG?? @North-Wind

Comment: You need JS to make a SVG (scalable vector graphics). Plotly makes a SVG, and you can change it using JS.

Answer (score 0):

I hope this will help you a little further... sorry if not.

```js
var xValue = ['1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9','10','11','12','13'];
var yValue = [10, 6, 8,9,1,17,3,7,13,2,12,4,13];
var wicket1 = ['W','','W','W','','','','W','','','','','W'];

var trace1 = {
  x: xValue,
  y: yValue,
  type: 'bar',
  text: wicket1,
  textposition: 'outside',
};

var data1 = [trace1];

Plotly.newPlot('myDiv', data1);


var container = document.getElementsByClassName("bartext")[0];
container.textContent = "Label";
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.plot.ly/plotly-latest.min.js"></script>
  <div id="myDiv"></div>
```